# data-method negates data-confirm on old jquery-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unobtrusive-javascript, jquery-rails

I'm supporting an old site running Rails 3.2, jquery 1.7, with a custom jquery-rails (the gemfile says it's 0.2.6 - but there's a custom one in the public folder, so it could have been updated)

I have a delete link (data-method=delete) with a confirmation (data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this?"). However, even if I click cancel on the confirm box, the item gets deleted. I'm guessing this has only started happening recently. Any ideas why this has started happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix this by hacking the jquery.rails.js with the following:

```
/**
 *  confirmation handler
 */
$('a[data-confirm],input[data-confirm]').live('click', function (event) {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.triggerAndReturn('confirm')) {
        if (!confirm(el.attr('data-confirm'))) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(event.currentTarget).data('failed-confirm', true);
            return false;
        }
        ...
```

This way, if the user clicks cancel, it sets data on the link that I can test for. Then, at the start of the data-method handler:

```
    $('a[data-method]:not([data-remote])').live('click', function (e){
        if($(e.currentTarget).data('failed-confirm')) {
            $(e.currentTarget).data('failed-confirm', false);
            return false;
        }
        ...
```

This seems to work, but I'm still intrigued as to what's changed...